# Menu Centralizado

Tags: html, css, menu

Estou tendo muitas dificuldades para alinhas o texto do meu menu ao centro, estou começando agora a aprender a desenvolver sites.

Imagem do site:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código está assim:

```
<center>
<h1>Meu Site</h1>
 <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Informações</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Novidades</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</center>
```

`css`:

```
    h1 {
        color:#00C
       }

    body {
        padding:0px;
        margin:auto;
        max-width: auto;
    }

    #menu ul {
        padding:0px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#999;
        list-style:none;
        font:80% Tahoma;
        alignment-adjust:central;
        max-width: auto;
    }

    #menu ul li { 
        display: inline;
        width: 520px;
        }

    #menu ul li a {
        background-color:999;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom:3px solid #EDEDED;
        padding: 2px 10px;
        float:left;
    }

    #menu ul li a:hover {
        background-color:#D6D6D6;
        color: #6D6D6D;
        border-bottom:3px solid #EA0000;
    }
```

Comment: Já que está começando agora, porque não usa o framework Botstrap:http://getbootstrap.com/? Vai ficar bem melhor.

Comment: Pois que conheço um pouco de HTML e CSS pois fiz curso mais ja faz muito tempo e estou voltando agora com muitas dificuldades. Preciso resolver este problema para prosseguir.

Comment: Está certo @Jesimiel, primeiro utilizar `<center>` é uma coisa que pra mim, só pesa o code, além de ser desnecessário pois tudo pode e deve ser alinhado pelo `css`

Answer (score 6):

Como disse no comentário, usar a tag `center` do `html` é perca de tempo, totalmente desnecessário e outras coisas.

Vamos organizar todos os alinhamentos pelo `css`. Prefiro não usar `ul li` para fazer menu, recomendo a você que também não use, ele é mais para ordenar itens e outros.

Nesse exemplo (que tem seu `html` como template) utilizei a tag `nav` que é especialmente para menu, facilitando muita coisa. Mas chega de conversa e vamos a solução.

O código é esse:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
header,
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background: #999;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px 8px;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EA0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Meu Site</h1>
<nav role='navigation'>
  <a href="#0">Home</a>
  <a href="#0">Informações</a>
  <a href="#0">Novidade</a>
  <a href="#0">Contato</a>
</nav>
```

A centralização de um elemento `block` é feita definindo sua `margin-left` e `margin-right` como `auto` (o elemento deve ter uma largura definida, caso contrário, sua largura seria 100% e não precisaria de centralização).

Basicamente é só isso, espero que seja isso que estava querendo ;)

Comment: Ow obrigado vou pesquisar sobre esse nav, e deu o visual perfeito que eu estava querendo vlw amigo

Comment: Não entendi o down vote, tem alguma coisa errada?

Comment: @Jesimiel Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, lembre de marcar como resposta correta (usando o botão de "correto" logo abaixo dos de votação)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma abaixo:

```css
h1 {
  color:#00C;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding:0px;
  margin:auto;
  max-width: auto;
}

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #999;
}

#menu ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  font: 80% Tahoma;
  alignment-adjust: central;
  max-width: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #777;
}

#menu ul li { 
  display: inline;
  width: 520px;
}

#menu ul li a {
  background-color:999;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom:3px solid #EDEDED;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  float:left;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#D6D6D6;
  color: #6D6D6D;
  border-bottom:3px solid #EA0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Meu Site</h1>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Informações</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Novidades</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Obs.: Evite usar a tag `<center>`, pois essa tag está obsoleta, e não mais pertence a especificação do `HTML5`. Uma opção para substituir a utilizanção dessa tag seria usar a propriedade `text-align:center;` do `css`.

Comment: Obrigado ajudou bastante

Answer (score -2):

Para você centralizar um menu, basta seguir o seguinte código:

#menu {
text-align: center;
}